# Effect of a cylindrical lens in front of a diffractive optical element (DOE) and 5mW red laser

Tags: optics, laser, diffraction, lenses

I want to expand the image formed by a [grid pattern diffractive optical element (DOE)](https://www.ebay.ca/itm/144002710336?_trkparms=aid%3D1110006%26algo%3DHOMESPLICE.SIM%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20140131123730%26meid%3Dfb1c5d3e79814c3d9c9f7dab94176aff%26pid%3D100167%26rk%3D1%26rkt%3D15%26sd%3D194025855582%26itm%3D144002710336%26pmt%3D0%26noa%3D1%26pg%3D5411%26algv%3DDefaultOrganic%26brand%3DUnbranded&_trksid=p5411.c100167.m2940). I will be using a 5mW red (650nm) laser. I thought maybe putting a cylindrical lens in front might spread the grid evenly in 1 direction, and a 2nd cylindrical lens at 90 deg would spread it in the other direction, yeilding an undistorted but larger grid. But seems not to be true. I spoke to a laser technician and he tried it with only 1 cylindrical lens, and told me it turned the grid into a 'blob'. Unfortunately not any more info than that.

1. Why would this occur?
2. Would a different lens combination be better?

Thank you!

Comment: Doesn't the grid pattern diverge with distance without any lens?

Comment: Yes, but there is a specified fan angle that is inadequate for my purposes. I  can't increase the distance far enough, so I want to enlarge the pattern

Comment: what happens when you pass it through a magnifying glass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your purposes the only solution is a DOE with higher spatial frequency, which leads to a more spread out grid.

The reason why it didn't work for you is because the laser beams are collimated, except you diffracted them into many diffraction orders, creating beamlets.

Using a lens, might collimate the angular separation (ie, stop the spread of the grid) but as a consequence the laser beamlets will be focused and then diverge themselves (just as you would use a single lens on a beam, it first focus, then diverges.)

Using a cylindrical lens, depending on the distance betwenn your DOE and lens, relative relative to the lens' focal length, you can either decrease the spread, make the grid non-spreading, or make it converge again, in one of the directions, but no matter what you do, your beamlets will always first focus and then diverge in that same direction, and in virtually all cases, rendering the beamlets useless for their purpose.

There are solutions using lenses for your purpose, but you would need a bit higher optics knowledge and find the solution yourself for your own set of constraints...but in that case you would not be asking here on SE.

Comment: just a comment, you would need lenses before and after the DOE with precise distances, precise focal lengths to match your problem. The easiest solution is to always have at hand a handful of DOEs with different spatial frequencies so you can adapt to any requirements.

Comment: ok thank you! i understand now. great explanation. yes, i only have basic optics knowledge. what if i just used a lens with a long enough focal length such that it did not start to diverge? my distance is only about 50cm to 1m

Comment: So, you want a bigger grid on the wall, right? (Could you say which factor bigger, current size at wall, and distance from DOE to wall?)

Comment: I must add though that I am finding it hard to think of any solution that might work, that uses a single lens. The only way I am seeing this working, if you want to maintain beamlet size, would be a beam expansion (2 lenses), then long focusing lens before the DOE with a confocal condition (same focus) to a concave lens (de-focusing) to collimate the beamlets and increase the spread rate of the grid, so, 4 lens minimum. But then the increase factor will be dependent on the last 2 lenses. (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) I do not doubt there being "solutions" using a single lens, but you trade off something in those cases, like the beamlets will be very big or the grid increase factor too small.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like a standard imaging magnification problem. However, th increase the angular spreading of the diffraction orders, you need to have a smaller spacing in your diffraction grating. You can achieve this by *de-magnifying* the image of the grating. For this purpose one can use a [4f system](https://www.opticsforhire.com/blog/4f-optical-system-fourier-optics), consisting of two lenses with $f_1$ and $f_2$ as their focal lengths. The (de)magnification factor is
$$ M = \frac{f_2}{f_1} . $$
Place the two lens at a distance of $f_1+f_2$ from each other. The input plane where the diffraction grating is located, is at a distance of $f_1$ in front of the first lens and the enlarge image would be obtained at a distance $f_2$ behind the second lens.

Comment: see my answer, this would not work. By your description you will image the grating surface, which means actually just a slightly bigger beam. If you instead decide to use as input plane, the plane where the pattern already has a size which is considerable, then you have the problem that your output pattern will not fit onto the lens (I assume this pattern is used on a wall with several meters per side). You completely disregard that the laser is collimated and the emerging pattern is not. You need to put more thought into a setup to image a (use-able) grid like that.

Comment: @JoséAndrade. You're right, if the 4f system magnifies the grating the angular spreading of the diffraction orders will be reduced. However, you are wrong when you say it cannot work. If the image of grating is de-magnified the angular spreading of the diffraction orders will be increased. I've edited the answer to make this clear.

Comment: I don't argue that you are right about the magnification of the grid, I argue that the grid uses a laser source, and the laser is collimated, resulting in point like projections on the wall from the diffraction grating. By using any kind of imaging setup just thinking about the grid image means neglecting the fact that each beamlet has completely different divergence compared to the grid. After your imaging setup each beam will be highly divergent and no sharp points will appear on the wall. Just try it yourself.

Comment: (or, in a perfect 4f-magnification configuration, the beamlets will be collimated, but with the de-magnification factor added to them, so, your grid will have bigger blobs, and as you have to sacrifice space for the telescope, you need to increase the de-magnification factor a lot....and you still have to fit the whole pattern on the lenses)

Comment: Not sure I understand your explanation, but it seems that you make a big issue of the "collimation" of the laser. Remember, no laser is perfectly collimated. The laser beam always have some divergence angle that cannot remove. Better to think in terms of the angular spectrum. If you want to expand the image, then you want to reduce the size of the angular spectrum.  That is effectively what I propose.